# Matplotlib ValueError

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I have been struggling with this problem for hours now, the code is as follows :

```
    for i in range(int(user_input)):
        summ = randint(1,10)+randint(1,10)+randint(1,10)+randint(1,10)
        x.append(summ)   
    print(x) 
    counts = np.bincount(np.array(x))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.bar(range(41), counts, width=0.8, align='center')
    ax.set(xticks=range(1,41), xlim=[0, 41])
    plt.show()
```

I am getting the following error:  i could not figure out why ?

**ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape**

log is pointing to this line :

`ax.bar(range(41), counts, width=0.8, align='center')`

Thanks

edit : @olenscki's answer is working but the outcomed plot is messy as you may see from the picture, any further help is appreciated :

edit 2: as suggested by @olenscki's comments, problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you `ax.bar` call you give the function 2 parameters: a range of 41 and a counts array. It occurs that the range(41) not always have the same dimension, the range will always have 41 numbers, but the count could have only 20 or 60 values. This will fix your problem:

```
ax.bar(range(len(counts)), counts, width=0.8, align='center')
```

With this, you will constrain the range to have the same dimension as counts

Comment: thank you, it is working, the x axis ticks are messed up though , you know how i may solve?

Comment: you may see the outcome in the updated question' edit

Comment: I noted that too, you could only delete the ```ax.set``` line. The mpl will automatically set the ticks for you, although it won't print it value by value. If you want it plotted value by value, you could increase the plot length declaring the plot dimensions like ```fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))``` or you could provide your own ticker paramethers to the plot, which is pretty much more complicated, but produces a better result, you can learn about the ticker formatter here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html